# how to use asynctask in android-support-v4.jar Fragment?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I have a TabActivity which has two tabs. I load separate Activity in each tab (Activity **A** & **B**). Activity A, which is loaded in tab 1 has **some controls** and a **ListView**. I use **AsyncTask** to load data from a web service for that **ListView**. I had to load another activity when user clicked on ListView item, but that new Activity **C** should be loaded in same selected Tab.

I searched on internet and found that i can use **ActivityGroup** ... but at the same time,i found that its deprecated. So using android-support-v4 compatibility **Frangment** were proposed..

I downloaded that **android-support-v4.jar** and looked at the **FragmentTabs** sample, I got it how can i use Fragments even in Android 2.1.... so i replaced the two **Activities**, which i was showing in tabs, with two **Fragments**

But now I dont know how to handle the follow situations:

1. ListView & Other controls does not show when i run the following code.
2. i have to call AsyncTask ... it will take time to get & parse XML data from the server and Fragment's **onCreateView** is called earlier ... so how can i set the **ListView** in fragment after its **onCreateView** is called?
3. After ListView item is clicked, i will have to load another fragment **C** within that same **tab** ... how can i achieve this?

Code for my Fragment is as follows:

```
public class UpdatesFragment extends Fragment implements IFeedReceiver {
ArrayList<Feed> _feeds;
Integer _currentPage = 1;
ListView _lvUpdates;
UserMessage _userMessage;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getFeeds();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.updates, container, false);
    this._lvUpdates = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listUpdates);

    return v;
}

private void getFeeds() {
    FeedsCollectorAsyncTask task = new FeedsCollectorAsyncTask(
            getActivity(), this._currentPage);
    task.execute();
}

//This method is called from AsyncTask upon receiving & parsing data. So i m trying to populate my ListView here
@Override
public void onFeedReceived(ArrayList<Feed> feeds) {
    FeedsAdapter adapter = new FeedsAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.feed_list_item, this._feeds);

    this._lvUpdates.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Load detail on item click
    this._lvUpdates.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int index,
                long id) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Main Tab Activity XML is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">        
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+android:id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-6dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And finally ...

```
public class PlayMakerActivity extends FragmentActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
TabHost tabHost;
TabManager mTabManager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
   // TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup();

    mTabManager = new TabManager(this, tabHost, R.id.realtabcontent);

    mTabManager.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Upudates").setIndicator("Updates"),
            UpdatesFragment.class, null);       
}
}

//also included the following AS It IS
public static class TabManager implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener {
    ....
    ....
    ....
}
```

You can point me to some example.
Your help is greatly appreciated!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am new to android development, but I have encountered a few of these issues with conversion to fragments, so I'll try to help as best I can.

1. This question ties in with the second I think, so I'll just ignore it and hope answer 2 addresses it well enough.
2. I ran into a similar situation where I converted an activity that used an AsyncTask into a fragment.  I'm not sure if this is good practice, but I simply moved my logic that was originally in the onCreate (in your situation, your ListView and your getFeeds() call) into the onCreateView method.
3. As far as fragment traversal, I used a base FragmentActivity that sets the first Fragment into the appropriate container in the FragmentActivitiy's layout.  If you're wanting to load another fragment, I believe you will reference your FragmentActivity's FragmentManager, start a new transaction and add a new fragment.  The [android developer website](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) explains all of this thoroughly.

If you're wanting to launch a new fragment directly from an open fragment, then you'll want to reference the host FragmentActivity using getActivity() first.  For example:

`FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();`

Hope this helps!

To everyone else:  I'm also new to answering question on here, so let me know if I should make changes to future responses I post.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer. I had other issues BUT one of their solution included what u suggested. So i will accept it as answer.. thanks again

Comment: No problem, glad I could help in some way lad.